# dijit.byId('viewEditParameterValue').value does not return while .get('value') does

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dijit.form

I have defined  two Text input in my html like this..

```
<revit:validationTextBox id="viewEditParameterValue" maxLength="2500" 
                                        required="true" 
                                        invalidMessage="#{commonuielements.msg_invalid_input}">
                                    </revit:validationTextBox>

<revit:validationTextBox id="viewEditParameterValDefault"
                                        maxLength="100" 
                                        regExp="#{commonuielements.parameter_default_value_regex}" 
                                        invalidMessage="#{commonuielements.msg_invalid_input}"
                                        trim="true"></revit:validationTextBox>
```

I am trying to get the value of two TextBox  in a java script function like this..

```
var value = dijit.byId('viewEditParameterValDefault').value;
var parValue = dijit.byId('viewEditParameterValue').value;
```

But for the first one I get the value but second line returns blank whereas If I use below line I get the value.

```
var parValue = dijit.byId('viewEditParameterValue').get('value');
```

Does anybody have any guess what could be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get('value')` is the correct way to retrieve the value of a Dijit form input widget.  Accessing `value` directly isn't guaranteed to give you consistent results (or the results you expect), since it will be implementation-dependent.  This is perhaps even more important for certain subclasses of TextBox where formatting or mapping come into play.

Moreover, *setting* `value` directly won't accomplish *anything*, whereas calling `set('value', ...)` will properly update the widget.